# Mismatch of R id in android

Tags: android

I have defined my layout file as:

```
  <ImageView        
        android:id="@+id/next_button"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:layout_centerVertical="true"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:clickable="true"            
        android:src="@drawable/next_button_image"/>
```

My java file `onClickListener` as:

```
   nextButton=(ImageView) findViewById(R.id.next_button);  
   nextButton.setOnClickListener(this);
    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
    System.out.println(v.getId()+"==="+R.id.next_button);
    switch (v.getId()) {
    case R.id.next_button:
        ++pageCount;
        setAnimalWithClick();
        break;
    case R.id.back_button:
        --pageCount;
        setAnimalWithClick();
        break;


    default:
        break;
    }

}
```

But it is not registering the click event.
The sysout that I have placed is giving me this output:

```
01-01 21:07:13.384: I/System.out(10678): 2131230723===2131230721
```

Why are the ids different? I tried cleaning and rebuilding. It did not workout.

Comment: Did you double check your XML to make sure you aren't using id/next_button in two spots?  (or including your xml file twice into another xml file)?

Answer (score 0):

I recommend using this pattern instead, and you don't have to have a giant switch statement and hope your ID's are managed correctly:

```
    nextButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            // Handle click
        }
    });
```